# How to align flat buttons in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm wondering how do I align buttons in flutter. I'm new to flutter and for my current code I'm not able to throw in any rows, column or wrap. I would like to align my buttons in a vertical manner but current its aligned horizontally and giving me a "RIGHT OVERFLOW BY 256 PIXELS" display error

```
                  return showDialog<void>(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          content: Text("You have $counts routes!"),
                          actions: <Widget>[
                            new FlatButton(
                              textColor: Colors.black,
                              padding:
                                  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 10),
                              child: Text(
                                  "This is route 1! \n" +
                                      rList[0] + "\n"),
                              onPressed: () {},
                            ),
                            new FlatButton(
                              textColor: Colors.black,
                              padding:
                                  EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 10),
                              child: Text(
                                  "This is your second route! \n" +
                                      rList[1] + "\n"),
                              onPressed: () {},
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      });
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just add your buttons to `Column`

```
actions: <Widget>[
    Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
        children: <Widget>[
            button,
            button
        ]
    )
],
```

or if you want that buttons was aligned to left side, move these buttons to `content`:

```
builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text("You have routes!"),
            new FlatButton(
              textColor: Colors.black,
              child: Text(
                  "This is route 1! \n" +
                      "\n"),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
            new FlatButton(
              textColor: Colors.black,
              child: Text(
                  "This is your second route! \n" +
                      "\n"),
              onPressed: () {},
            )
          ],
        ),
      );
    });
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the prompt reply! Now that it is aligned how do i push my buttons to the left side in? This is current how mine looks like and i would like to align it in line with the first statement.
https://imgur.com/a/AONgmmM

Comment: @nevertoolateyet try change `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start`

Comment: @nevertoolateyet try to move your buttons to `content`. Please see my example https://gist.github.com/Oleksandr32/3b385e2135e5b7b5f3c23e6e6cc8c8c2

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ListView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html) for synchronizing row by row automatically.

Check below sample for ListView.You should paste it on **body segment** of your code.

```
//some of codes..

    body: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15, left: 15, right: 15),
      child: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[ 
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Confirm"),
            color: Colors.lightGreen,
            elevation: 5.0,
            onPressed: () {
              save(1,context);
              /*  some of codes */
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Cancel"),
            color: Colors.redAccent,
            elevation: 5.0,
            onPressed: () {
              save(0,context);
              /*  some of codes */
            },
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Pass"),
            color: Colors.yellowAccent,
            elevation: 5.0,
            onPressed: () {
              save(2,context);
              /*  some of codes */
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
```